# How to configure systemd service to start a service that requires another service to be running, but only at startime

Tags: systemd

I would like to configure a not so common start sequence with systemd:
Service A is required by service B only while service B is starting.
Once Service B started, Service A can be stopped and Service B can go on running.

If Service B tries to start, and Service A is stopped, then one of these 
 must happen: Service A must start or not. If not, Service B must not start.

So, Service A is required by Service B only at start time of B. Otherwise, Service A is irrelevant.

I have checked the system.unit options (requires, requisites, wants, before, after, etc), and I cannot find the right mix to achieve such behaviour.

Comment: If A isn't required by other services, then this logic can be implemented inside service B

Comment: Yes, it truly could. We try to avoid additional scripts. Service A and Service B are two processes started by Out-Of-The-Box scripts. Service B does not implement the is-process-A-running check, but otherwise starts with errors. So, a solution would be to implement this checks in a script. We will try it and we will check if it   is functional. We can have a lot of processess type B, but just one type A. So we do not like the idea of a single systemd unit starting services type B via the service@instance syntax, and checking for Service A at one time.

Comment: If A is not needed by other parts of your system, then a separate service is not needed, a single service can contain any number of processes. I'm not talking about unit instance. A script check for the status of A(and run A if necessary) and then start B would solve your problem. Why do you avoid additional script?

Answer (score 1):

You could have **B** require **A** with `Requires=` and kill **A** using `ExecStartPost=` in **B**

Comment: We do not need Service A to get killed. Service A is also useful. But it is only mandatory at Service B startup.